# Trying to write a small C# application implementing the Twitter API

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth, linq-to-twitter

I am relatively new to C# and I am trying to write an application that reads all of the latest tweets from a user and spits out a list of the links to a text file.

Would I just need the twitter API and streamwriter? 
Is there anything I am overlooking?

This will be my first useful app and I am trying to figure out if I am getting over my head here.

Comment: Which Twitter API?  Is there no documentation there that helps you get started?

Comment: @DStanley well, that's kind of why I asked on here.Is there any reason or benefit to using a wrapper? If not, it seems like the standard Twitter api would make the most sense, wouldn't it?

Comment: Start there, get something that _works_, then think of ways to make it _better_.  Don't over-complicate it or start by trying to develop an enterprise-worthy app if you're just learning.  Don;t fix problems that aren't  there.

Comment: @DStanley Good advice, I'll start with the basic API and Google my way through it. I'll report back if I need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of [Tweetinvi](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi) which is Portable Class Library allowing you to access Twitter REST API very simply.

> Would I just need the twitter API and streamwriter? Is there anything I am overlooking?

In theory it would be the case but there are many things you need to consider when accessing the Twitter API. Authentication, not documented endpoints, not documented parameters, fields that have different type of values based on the enpoint (e.g. string vs. int)... Tweetinvi will take care of this for you and in addition you will have a access to a set of tools simplifying your life (e.g. RateLimits).

By using a wrapper you won't have to consider any of the problems you can encounter from the Twitter API.

Here is an example of what you want to achieve:

```
Auth.SetUserCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", "ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");
var userId = 1577389800;
var userLatestTweets = Timeline.GetUserTimeline(userId);
```

Comment: The answer to "Too Broad" questions is not "Use my library", but to vote to close as "Too Broad".

Comment: The answer is not "use my library" but an explanation of why he should prefer using a wrapper instead of doing it himself. In addition there is an example of what he is trying to do "read all of the latest tweets from a user".

Comment: Thank you for explaining the stuff I was overlooking. I will look into wrappers to make things more simple.

Comment: If you think this answer your question, please set it as answered.